# bash: URL: command not found

Tags: bash, url

I keep getting the following error in bash (using windows):

```
$ URL = "https://nyc-tlc.s3.amazonaws.com/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2022-01.parquet"
bash: URL: command not found
```

The full command i am trying to run in bash is:

```
URL = "https://nyc-tlc.s3.amazonaws.com/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2022-01.parquet"

python ingest_data.py \
  --user=root \
  --password=root \
  --host=localhost \
  --port=5432 \
  --db=ny_taxi \
  --table_name=yellow_taxi_trips \
  --url=${URL}
```

Running the full command runs the ingest_data.py file but no download happens (I uassume because of this `URL: command not found` error.

If I run ingest_data.py then nothing happens - similar to running the full command above.

The 'important' part of ingest_data.py file for using the URL is `os.system(f"wget {url} -0 {flatfile_parquet}")`:

```
def main(params):
    user = params.user
    password = params.password
    host = params.host
    port = params.port
    db = params.db
    table_name = params.table_name
    url = params.url
    flatfile_parquet = 'output.parquet'
    
    # download the parquet file
    os.system(f"wget {url} -0 {flatfile_parquet}")
    
    # connect to server
    engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db}')
```

I keep finding threads that say to use curl but I dont want to download the file in bash, I want to store the url in  a variable and then use it in the `ingest_data.py` file.

Any advice is appreciated, i'm kind of a noob with bash

Comment: You cannot have whitespace on either side of the `=` when assigning a value to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error on your first line.  You cannot leave spaces around the "=" or else BASH will attempt to run the first word as a command.  Consider:

```
$ a = "xx"
bash: a: command not found
$ echo = "xx"
= xx
$ a="xx"
$ echo "$a"
xx
```

You should use:

```
$ URL="https://nyc-tlc.s3.amazonaws.com/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2022-01.parquet"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! but still no download happening so more debugging to be done! thanks!!

Comment: @RedRum start by double -quoting your variables when you use them. So the last parameter to your python invocation should become `--url="$URL"`